# What's the most general geometry of curves and surfaces (in particular, to study tangents and envelopes)?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

> What is the most general geometry of curves and surfaces?

For example, at curves, we define in differential geometry the tangent vector as the derivative of a regular curve, but visually many other curves that are not regular admit tangent at any point. I saw that we can define supporting lines, tangent cones, and bitangents for a curve in convex geometry. What branch of geometry studies them in a general manner?

Another example: I want to study the envelope of a 1-parameter family of curves, but I don't know what definition should I use. The idea is that a curve is an envelope for a family of curves if each point is on some curve of the family and the tangents at that point of contact with respect to the envelope and to the respective curve on the family are collinear. But HOW CAN WE DEFINE THE TANGENT TO A CURVE IN THE MOST GENERAL WAY?

Can you give me some references?

Comment: Set theory! :-)

Comment: Logic. State as axioms the basic properties you want, and take a language of 'curves', 'lines' (perhaps 'vectors') with a central predicate '*to be tangent*'.

Comment: [In response to your penultimate sentence.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctbYddoY9TQ)

Comment: To obtain the envelope of the family of curves $f(x,y;\lambda)=0$, you eliminate $\lambda$ between this equation and $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial\lambda}f(x,y;\lambda)=0$.

Comment: Diffeology is a generalization of differential geometry.